# How to pass SID to url?

Tags: session, core-session

I see here many questions how to remove SID. It seems this is not very rare. How that even happen? Even if php ini settings for `session.use_trans_sid` is `true` and Magento setting `Use SID on Frontend` set to `Yes`, Magento won't pass SID to url.

So in which situation SID will appear in url? How can you pass SID to url, is that something that can be done only if you change core url model or are there any other ways?